# BigQuery Hadoop connector & Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Is the [BigQuery Hadoop connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector) automatically deployed with a [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [BigQuery Hadoop connector](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bigquery-connector) is automatically deployed with [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) clusters. The [Dataproc version detail](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/dataproc-versions) page lists which version of the Google Cloud Platform connectors, including the BigQuery connector, are included with each Dataproc release.