# Google DataProc API spark cluster with c#

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have data in Big Query I want to run analytics on in a spark cluster. Per documentation if I instantiate a spark cluster it should come with a Big Query connector. I was looking for any sample code to do this, found one in [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045381/384554). Could not find any c# examples. Also found some [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dataproc/v1/csharp/latest/annotated.html) on the functions in DataProc APIs nuget package.

Looking for a sample to start a spark cluster in Google cloud using c#.

Comment: Thank you for asking this. As I was preparing an example, I realized the autogenerated V1 API available on nuget is out of date and does not contain the methods needed to do this. I'm going to work on getting that pushed ASAP. I'll update here when packages are updated.

Comment: @AngusDavis Thanks for replying.Any ideas how long it will be before the sample and the new package will be ready?

Comment: The NuGet packages have been updated. I'll work on getting a small sample together.

Answer (score 2):

After installing Google.Apis.Dataproc.v1 version 1.10.0.40 (or higher):

Below is a quick sample console app for creating a Dataproc cluster in C#:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2; 
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Dataproc.v1; 
using Google.Apis.Dataproc.v1.Data;

using System; 
using System.Threading;

namespace DataprocSample {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string project = "YOUR PROJECT HERE";
            string dataprocGlobalRegion = "global";
            string zone = "us-east1-b";
            string machineType = "n1-standard-4";
            string clusterName = "sample-cluster";
            int numWorkers = 2;
            // See the docs for Application Default Credentials:
            // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
            // In general, a previous 'gcloud auth login' will suffice if running as yourself.
            // If running from a VM, ensure the VM was started such that the service account has
            // the CLOUD_PLATFORM scope. 
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result;
            if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
            {
                credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[] { DataprocService.Scope.CloudPlatform });
            }

            DataprocService service = new DataprocService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Dataproc Sample",
                });

            // Create a new cluster:
            Cluster newCluster = new Cluster
            {
                ClusterName = clusterName,
                Config = new ClusterConfig
                {
                    GceClusterConfig = new GceClusterConfig
                    {
                        ZoneUri = String.Format(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{0}/zones/{1}",
                            project, zone),
                    },
                    MasterConfig = new InstanceGroupConfig
                    {
                        NumInstances = 1,
                        MachineTypeUri = String.Format(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{0}/zones/{1}/machineTypes/{2}",
                            project, zone, machineType),
                    },
                    WorkerConfig = new InstanceGroupConfig
                    {
                        NumInstances = numWorkers,
                        MachineTypeUri = String.Format(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{0}/zones/{1}/machineTypes/{2}",
                            project, zone, machineType),
                    },
                },
            };
            Operation createOperation = 
                service.Projects.Regions.Clusters.Create(newCluster, project, dataprocGlobalRegion).Execute();
            // Poll the operation:
            while (!IsDone(createOperation))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Polling operation {0}", createOperation.Name);
                createOperation =
                    service.Projects.Regions.Operations.Get(createOperation.Name).Execute();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done creating cluster {0}", newCluster.ClusterName);
        }
        static bool IsDone(Operation op)
        {
            return op.Done ?? false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am trying to authenticate using `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync` I did download our service key file and pointed `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to it but still get the exception. `System.InvalidOperationException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.`

Comment: Do we need permissions to Google Compute Engine & Google Cloud Dataproc before we can try starting a cluster?

Comment: @TeslaCodes - You'll want to ensure Dataproc and Compute Engine APIs are enabled (the easiest way to do this is to go to the compute engine and Dataproc screens in Cloud Console). The error message you're seeing seems to indicate the client library is having trouble getting credentials. If you're running your app on GCE, ensure the VM has a service account and the service account has access to all cloud APIs by specifying the CLOUD_PLATFORM OAuth scope (this is the easiest way). If running locally, try printing out the value of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and the value of FileInfo.Exists.

Comment: Printed GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS it printed path to my key, Still got the same error. So switched to same authentication code I use for authenticating with GCS. But now get a different error posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760854/request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes-when-creating-a-cluster-with-goog